# Headphone jack broken for music, yet works perfectly for telephone calls

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

I have a peculiar problem when using headphones on my iPhone SE.

When playing music, podcasts, videos, or doing Facetime calls, sound only comes through the right side. Yet when I make a telephone call, audio comes through both sides / ears.

Some things I've tried:

- Cleaned the headphone port with a cotton swab and with a paperclip.
- Ensured the "channel" slider in Accessibility settings is centered.
- Tried different pairs of headphones.

None of the above affects the issue. Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely music, etc is in stereo, while telephone voice audio is in mono. Mono goes to both channels, but in stereo, its separate channels. If this is the case, perhaps one of the channels is broken on your headphone plug (or jack). In other words, L or R is broken.

Of course, your options are repair, or try a different set of headphones or since this is an SE, you have the option of using the Lightning port as a headphone jack. Simply purchase a Lightning to headphone adapter from Apple, and you should get the audio back.

Comment: I had the same suspicion - that telephone voice audio is mono channel. But I've also selected "mono audio" in Accessibility -> Hearing, to no effect. If the issue was stereo audio only, wouldn't that fix the issue?